# appendChild type mismatch error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I've been working on applying a simple sort to columns on a table that can sort the whole table when the column header is clicked. The attached code works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome , IE10 and above. But i get the appendChild: type mismatch error in IE 8. I'm aware there is a jQuery program called tablesorter but ideally i want to keep it to a simple javascript function.   Can anyone advise what i need to do to get the sorting working in IE8?

here's the jsfiddle to have a look at the code and see it working in modern browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/gj0k0sod/ ( new jsfiddle using innerHTML)

The javascript function used to sort the table itself when a column is clicked

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
   var tbcount = table.rows.length - 2,
       tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
       i;

   var tr = [];
   for (i = 0; i < tbcount; i++) {
       tr.push(tb.rows[i]);
   }

   reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
   tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
       return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
           * (a.cells[col].innerHTML // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
               .localeCompare(b.cells[col].innerHTML)
              );
   });

   for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order

   sortOrder = sortOrder * -1;
}
```

Comment: Does `String.prototype.trim()` even exist in IE8?

Comment: No, and also `textContent` isn't supported in IE8.

Comment: @Teemu I wondered about that, too...

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for highlighting that textContent is not supported in IE 8, i replaced it with innerHTML  and the same error is still happening for appendChild.